# Windows Form DataGridView AutoSizing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My friend and I are trying to do some Autosizing with our DataGridView.
Right now, we have set the AutoSizeColumn to "Fill" which we want to do as it fits the box.
Now, what we don't want, is that it resizes all the Columns to the same size. What I mean with this is, that the Column "ID" and "Name" is the same size.

In ID there might be "5" which have A LOT of extra space while in Name "//SomeRandomLongName//" don't have enough space to show the full name. Is there a way to give ID less space while giving "Name" more space while still having it on "Fill"?

Hope you can help.
Nicklas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FillWeight` property of `DataGridViewColumn` to control the proportions of columns whose `AutoSizeMode` property is set to **Fill**. 
E.g. in your case when you know for sure that ID column will store only short (in respect to names) numbers you can decrease its fill weight. If you set `FillWeight` of ID column to lets say 1 and `FillWeight` of Name column to 5 that will mean that Name column will have five times more space than ID column and both columns will still resize themselves to fill all the available space.

The actual values of this property are not important by themselves only comparative to each other i.e. you can set them to 500 and 100 and have the same effect

Comment: I have tried to look into the FillWeight, and as far as I have been able to read that means that I need to make my own colums etc. and I don't want that, I am currently getting all of the colums from my Database. that's the only ways of FillWeight I have found, if you got any exampels as of how it can be done otherwise I'd like to hear it

Comment: You can bind your DataGridView to your DataTable at design time thus having all columns generated for you and being able to configure them the way you like